# Python - Intcheck Function Not Working

Tags: python

Here is my code below, for some reason the input from the question prints out again and then invalid input is shown:

## Integer checking function below

```
def intcheck(Answer):
    while True:
        try:
            response = int(input(Answer))
        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid Input")
        continue

        if repsonse not in range(0,4):
            print("Number not in range, Please enter a number between 1 and 4")
        else:
            return response

question_correct = 0

question_List = ["How do you write number 1 in Maori?",
                  "What is does tahi + tahi = ?",
                  "How do you write blue in Maori?",
                  "What two colours make blue?",
                  "Who was the god of the forest and birds?",
                  "Who were Tane Mahutas Parents?"]

question_Answer = ["1. Tahi 2.Rimu 3.Ono 4.Rua:",
                   "1.Kakariki 2.Kikorangi 3.Whero 4.Ma",
                   "1.Ma + Whero 2.Kikorangi + Kowhai 3.Whero + Pararui 4.Ma + Mangu",
                   "1.Ranginui 2.Paptuanuku 3.Tane-Mahuta 4.Tangaroa",
                   "1.Tangaroa + Ranguinui 2.Punga + Ranganui 3.Tangaroa + Rongo 4.Papatunuku + Ranganui"]

correct_Answer = ["4","2", "2","3","4",]

print (question_List[0])

Answer = intcheck(input(question_Answer[0]))
```

#### Result:

```
How do you write number 1 in Maori?
1.Tahi 2.Rimu 3.Ono 4.Rua:g
  g
 Invalid Input
  g
 Invalid Input
  g
```

I don't want the input to print itself again please help I'm just a beginner.

Comment: Please fix your indentation; as presented, this is invalid Python code.

Comment: sorry I don't know how to, why do people negative post

Comment: 1) paste code 2) select code 3) hit Ctrl+K

Comment: Thank you Aran-Fey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `input` again inside `intcheck`:

> ```
> def intcheck(Answer):
>     ...
>     response = int(input(Answer))
> ```

If you enter `g` for the first time, this will not try to convert `g` to a number, but will ask you for another value with the prompt `'g'`.

Change that line to:

```
response = int(Answer)
```